# Conditional JavaAgent Command for SBT Native Packager

Tags: scala, sbt, javaagents, datadog, sbt-native-packager

I'm using scala, sbt, sbt-native-package, and potentially sbt-java-agent to conditionally activate a datadog java agent at runtime w/ kubernetes.

By adding the `dd-java-agent` as a dependency and adding a script snippet, I'm able to activate datadog only when a specific env. variable is set, but this is also adding the dd-java-agent to the classpath, which I'm trying to avoid:

```scala
val DataDogAgentVersion = "0.70.0"

libraryDependencies += "com.datadoghq" % "dd-java-agent" % DataDogAgentVersion % "runtime"

bashScriptExtraDefines += """if [ "$DD_PROFILING_ENABLED" = "true" ]; then addJava "-javaagent:${app_home}/../lib/dd-java-agent-""" + DataDogAgentVersion + """.jar"; fi""""
```

Is there a way to have sbt manage the downloading of dd-java-agent.jar, include this jar in the `lib` directory (or a different directory if that's what it takes), but exclude from classpath?

I've tried using `sbt-java-agent` which puts the jar in a `dd-java-agent` directory and excludes the jar from the classpath, but I can not figure out how to wrap the `addJava` statement in an `if` check when using that plugin.

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ended up going with the `sbt-javaagent` plugin to avoid extra code to exclude the agent jar from the classpath, which the plugin handles automatically.

The trick/hack was to filter out the default [`addJava -javaagent` line the `sbt-javaagent` plugin adds automatically](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-javaagent/blob/v0.1.6/src/main/scala/com/lightbend/sbt/javaagent/JavaAgentPackaging.scala#L41), and then appending a new script snippent to only enable the javaagent when a certain env. variable is set.

```scala
lazy val dataDogAgentName = "dd-java-agent"
lazy val dataDogAgentVersion = "0.70.0"

lazy val distProject = project
  .enablePlugins(JavaAgent, JavaAppPackaging)
  .settings(
    javaAgents += "com.datadoghq" % dataDogAgentName % dataDogAgentVersion,
    bashScriptExtraDefines := bashScriptExtraDefines.value.filterNot(_.contains("javaagent")) :+ s"""
      |if [[ "$$DD_PROFILING_ENABLED" = "true" ]]; then
      |  addJava "-javaagent:$${app_home}/../$dataDogAgentName/$dataDogAgentName-$dataDogAgentVersion.jar";
      |fi
      |""".stripMargin,
  )
```

Comment: Thanks for having shared this

Comment: But finally how are you passing agent arguments ? 
`.settings(
    javaAgents += JavaAgent("com.datadoghq" % dataDogAgentName % dataDogAgentVersion,
    arguments = "my agent arguments")
  ) ` 
-> seems to be overriden at the ends and putting them directly into custom script does not work too.

Comment: Hi @Xorr, in my scenario I didn't need to pass any custom args, but I think you may be able to append them by adding a colon at the end of the custom script javaagent string. `addJava "-javaagent:$${app_home}/../$dataDogAgentName/$dataDogAgentName-$dataDogAgentVersion.jar:custom-args";`